# Javascript getting an attribute

Tags: javascript

A program that I am looking at creates an object literal as shown below:

`const order = {id: (id = button.getAttribute("data-order"))}`

`button.getAttribute("data-order")` returns the `value` for an `attribute` in a certain html element. However, I don't get why the returned `value` is getting stored in an `id` variable before being given to the `id` object attribute. Later in the program, it seems that the object has the correct value for the `id` attribute. How is the returned value (which has just been assigned to the 'id' variable) still able to be assigned to the object's 'id' attribute?

Comment: Best to ask whoever wrote this

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. You've just jammed some words together that don't make much sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this in your chrome dev console(Ctrl + Shift + I) : `id = 3`. This returns 3.
That is how the correct value is assigned to the `order` object property. The text inside the bracket returns the correct value from the `getAttribute` function.

Regarding why it was written this way, i assume it could help assign a value to the global `id` variable as well as the order object `id` property at the same time. You might want to load your id from someplace else in future, and will only have to change in this one place instead of 2.

Note: even if your `id` is not declared before that, it will be created as a variable and you can use it.

Comment: Thank you. I come from a different language so I have never see this kind of syntax.

Comment: No issues. I hope i was able to help you. Let me know if something is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

What happens here:

- Execute `button.getAttribute` with argv0 being `String("data-order")` (let's say this results in "test")
- Assign the value of the existing global or local variable `id` to "test" (the result) and then replace/"return" the assignment expression with "test" (becomes `{ id: "test" }`
- Assign order to `{ id: "test" }`

Comment: How is the returned value (which has just been assigned to the 'id' variable) still able to be assigned to the object's ' id' attribute? I come from a different language that doesn't support this kind of operation.

Comment: The assignment operator just returns the value. If this helped, please accept my answer